# Triangle button color problem in Safari (Pure CSS)

Tags: html, css, safari

Here is my code:

```css
button {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border-width: 0;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
outline: none !important;
width: 0;
height: 0;
float: left;
}

#buttonred {
-webkit-animation: buttonred 2s infinite step-start;
}

@-webkit-keyframes buttonred {
33.333% { 
border-radius: 0%;
background-color: red;
border-left: 0px solid transparent;
border-right: 0px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 0px solid red;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}
66.666% {
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: red;
border-left: 0px solid transparent;
border-right: 0px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 0px solid red;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}
100% { 
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 25px solid transparent;
border-right: 25px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 50px solid red;
background-color: transparent;
background: transparent;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
-webkit-border-radius:0; 
box-shadow: none;
backface-visibility:hidden;
}
}
```

```html
<button id="buttonred" class="colorchanger"  value="red"></button>
```

The color of the triangle should be »pure« red. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox. But not in Safari. Why? How is it possible to solve the problem? If you click the button, the color is correct for a short moment. I have tried a lot, but can't find a solution.

Would be so thankful for help!

Comment: what the onclick is supposed to do? is it relevant to the question?

Comment: No, has nothing to do with the question. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
#buttonred {
-webkit-animation: buttonred 2s infinite step-start;
border-bottom: 50px solid red;
}
```

Probably it's a Safari bug or something like that. The »border-bottom: 50px solid red;« is necessary here.

Love.